# How to check if my nvidia discrete graphic card is working now or not?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 15.04.
I have tried the following command:

```
lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA
```

But it always shows me the same results (both graphic cards) even with `bumblebee` installed, so I don't trust it.
Or maybe Unity is so heavy that it needs my both cards all the time ?

Comment: Note: the Ubuntu version is `15.04` - the `0` is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nvidia-smi -q | less` in the shell/Terminal/bash

More info: `nvidia-smi -h` and `man nvidia-smi`

Comment: Sorry, I should have written more details. I'm not using proprietary drivers for Nvidia now, just the default nouveau. Bumblebee is installed with "--no-install-recommends" option. So probably thats the reason I don't have nvidia-smi tool in my system.

Comment: Well, then you might have luck with finding similar tool for either bumblebee or possibly X